# What is the Best practice to store the image in Room database in android?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-room

i got image content uri from activity result like this

```
val imagePickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), onResult = { uri->
    it?.let {
        profilePhoto = uri.toString()
    }
})
```

1. should i convert it to byte array and store it as blob ?
2. should i copy the file to app specific folder and store that path to room ?

bast solution to do this

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 May or may not be feasible/practical due to how the Android API retrieves data via a Cursor.

- A Cursor is a buffer for retrieving some of the available rows.

  - The Cursor must be able to accommodate/hold at least 1 row, it cannot accommodate/hold part of a row.
  - It's size is limited to up to 4MB.
  - If an image is greater then 4MB then it cannot be extracted directly, it would have to be split into portions. e.g. [How to use images in Android SQLite that are larger than the limitations of a CursorWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321154/how-to-use-images-in-android-sqlite-that-are-larger-than-the-limitations-of-a-cu/55321155#55321155)

Option 1 would, again depending upon the size, possibly (probably) make poor use of the buffering and be inefficient and thus resource intensive.

As such Option 2 is considered the recommended approach even though in some circumstances SQLite can be more efficient/faster for storing data as per [SQLite 35% faster than the Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html)